# How to execute code after adding a specific reaction by a specific person in discord.py?

Tags: discord.py

I have this code:

```py
await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji == '✅')
```

I want the code to execute only after a specific user (variable gracz1) adds a reaction to the message (variable msg). For now, the code is executing without any user interaction.

Can you help me with that?

Comment: I think from reading the documentation, you can do something like that:
`await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction: reaction.emoji == '✅' and reaction.author == gracz1)`

Comment: sorry it's more like:
`await self.bot.wait_for('reaction_add', check=lambda reaction, user: reaction.emoji == '✅' and user.id == gracz1)`

Comment: What about checking if a reaction has been added to a specific message?

Comment: You say you want the code to execute if reaction is from a specific user. Is the code I proposed to you not working?

Comment: It works, but I would also like it to only work after adding a response to the message "msg".

Comment: I noticed that for me, I need to add a sleep after the bot adds the emoji. For whatever reason, when I add a reaction and then wait for reactions it triggers the code to run. Maybe adding a sleep above the wait for would work for you.